# Add loading progress to AJAX url fetch

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I woundered if it would be possible to add a loading progress i.e. 67% to my AJAX url fetch, to the below code?:

```
            function update() {
          $("#notice_div").html('<font color="yellow">Henter data fra <?php echo $storeName; ?>..'); 
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getOrders.php?gs=<?php echo $_SESSION['store'] ?>',
            timeout: 2000,
            success: function(data) {
              $("#orders").html(data);
              $("#notice_div").html('<font color="green">OK</font>'); 
              window.setTimeout(update, 10000);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              $("#notice_div").html('<font color="red">Det lykkedes ikke at kontakte server..</font>');
              window.setTimeout(update, 60000);
            }
        });
        }
```

While saying "Henter data fra: ... (67%)" e.t.c.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not with PHP as, to the best of my knowledge, PHP has no way of receiving a request before it's fully sent to the server.

Comment: But, how about with AJAX/jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Its Possible in some situations but not feasible for such lite operation. Do you want the progressbar to indicate  progress of uploading form data ? or you want to indicate progress of downloading response data ? If you are uploading some File Yes you can have a parallel query which will provide you feed on interval. But for this small communication overhead where most of the time its the processing delay from server side Its hard to design a progress relay unless you know the distinct stages of processing.

and It has nothing to do with PHP or what client side library you are playing with. you need to design both sides and is similar task in every other language

Comment: To the contrary, the answer has to do with both the front and the backend (i.e. PHP and Javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with JQuery alone because it has no access to the browser's request data, if I'm not mistaken.

The only way it can be done is if you're using a backend that supports partial request processing, in which case you can open a separate connection simultaneously to the backend and either poll for or push out upload progress for a given file id. But, as I said, PHP doesn't support partial requests, so you can't do this.